# Stop Search param in directories by grep immediately after param match

Tags: linux

hi friends I use the following command to find under /var some param in my script

grep -R "param" /var/* 2>/dev/null |grep -wq "param"

my problem is that: after grep find the param in file grep continue to search until all searches under /var/* will completed

How to perform stop immediately after grep match the param word

For example when I run the: grep -R "param" /var/* 2>/dev/null |grep -wq "param"

grep find the param after one second.

But grep continue to Search other same param on other files and its take almost 30 seconds

How to stop the grep immediately after param match?

THX

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
grep -m 1
```

to stop after the first match.

Comment: another quastion
if I want to add time out to grep , is it posible?
and if not how can I stop grep after 10 seconds.
THX

Comment: @yael: Make it into a script, and at the start of the script put something like: "( sleep 5 ; echo Warning $0 hanging - aborted ; kill -9 $$ ) &; TIMEOUT_PID=$!".
At the end of the script put: "kill -9 $TIMEOUT_PID".